# How to compare selectors?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the following block to test whether the element is the "Paste" item of the UIMenuController.

```
^(id element){
  return [element respondsToSelector:@selector(action)] && [element action] == @selector(paste:)
}
```

The compiler reported the error: "Comparison of distinct block types ('void (^ _Nullable)(void)' and 'SEL')".

How to make this comparing work?

Comment: What is the data type of `element` and its `action` property?

Comment: @mschmidt Can't use 'element.action' as type of elment is unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `element` is declared as `id`, the compiler has no way to know for sure what the data type of `action` is. It essentially finds any reference to a method named `action` and assumes whatever type it finds. But this might not be the correct `action` with the desired type of `SEL`.

You can use a cast to tell the compiler, don't worry, this `action` will return a `SEL`. Of course, if your assumption is wrong at runtime, your app may crash.

```
return [element respondsToSelector:@selector(action)] && [(UIMenuItem *)element action] == @selector(paste:)
```

This ensures the correct `action` method is used by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I actually tried that and got "Cast of a block pointer to 'SEL' is disallowed with ARC".

Comment: Hmmm. Try: `...&& [(UIMenuItem *)element action] ==...`.